# Getting value from an input field in html off a button click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a button and input field, and want to send the value of that field into an ajax call. I'm having a brain freeze at the moment and could use some help. Here's what I have so far.

```js
                function submit() {
                    $.ajax({
                      type: 'POST',
                      url: 'http://localhost:8000/getCoords',
                      dataType: 'json',
                      data: {name: 'Abduh'},
                      success: (success) => {
                        console.log(success);
                      },
                      error: (error) => {
                        console.log(error);
                      }
                    });
                }
```

```html
   <input type=text id=search placeholder=Search />
   <br/>
   <button id=submit onclick="submit()">Submit</button>
```

Comment: check in your browser  console for error

Comment: Somethng like `{name: $("search").val()}`

Comment: can you give me an example carsten?

Comment: @Milos you should be able yourself to insert my code into yourself. just looks for the common thing in both` hint, name

Answer (score 0):

you should sue quote around properties values

```
<input type='text' id='search' placeholder=Search />
<br/>
<button id='submit' onclick="submit();">Submit</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 $("#submit").on("click",function(){
    var  url= 'http://localhost:8000/getCoords';
    $.post( url, { name: $("#search").val() }).done(function(data) {
        alert( "Data Loaded: " + data );
      });
  });
```

---

```
<input type="text" id="search" placeholder="Search" />
<button id="submit">Submit</button>
```